# Не могу разобраться с подключением библиотеки CoolProp для Java

Tags: java, библиотеки

Доброго времени суток. Имеется сайт http://www.coolprop.org/ - база данных термодинамических свойств жидкостей. Я хочу подключить себе эту базу, чтобы пользоваться готовыми методами. Вот [страница с инструкцией](http://www.coolprop.org/coolprop/wrappers/Java/index.html#java) . Я скачал **platform-independent.7z** и распаковал, там куча классов, как я понял. Далее не совсем понятна строка "Download the special Java shared library for your....." ведь в этом предложении даются ссылки на то же место, что я выше описал. Ну и в конце концов я сделал на рабочем столе папку **мain** с таким же содержанием, но куда теперь ее помещать? 
Дело в том, что я смотрел как инклюдить библиотеки в java, и как я понял, у файлов должно быть расширение .jar, а тут совсем другой. В общем помогите пожалуйста разобраться как правильно подключить эту библиотеку. Сам я пользуюсь idea. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Это не база, а несколько классов, т.е. "либа" - библиотека. А "подключать" так же как и любые другие классы: добавить в `ClassPath` и сделать импорт `import` в свой проект.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сама библиотека написана на C++, а на Java написан просто интерфейс. Кроме **platform-independent.7z** (эта часть не завист от платформы), вам необходимо скачать библиотеку (она зависит от платформы).

Что бы подключить вам надо:

1. Распаковать архив **platform-independent.7z** в отдельную директорию
2. Скомпилировать все java файлы из него
3. В IDEA в Project structure -> Modules -> Ваш модуль -> Dependencies -> "+" -> JAR or directories...
4. Выберите директорию где у вас скомпилированные java файлы из **platform-independent.7z**
5. Библиотеку нужно поместить в директорию и указать её в `java.library.path`

Comment: Спасибо. Еще день парился над этой проблемой. На windows так и не смог, сделал тоже самое на arch linux - все работает